# Whethere we have $(a_1+...+a_n)(a_1^2+...+ a_n^2)\le n(a_1^3+...+a_n^3)$?

Tags: inequality

I think 
$$
(a_1+...+a_n)(a_1^2+...+ a_n^2)\le n(a_1^3+...+a_n^3)
$$
is right for all $a_i\in \mathbb R$. But I don't how to show it ,seemly, induction is not valid. I only verify it is right for $n=2$. Whether it is right for all $n$ and $a_i\in \mathbb R$? How to show it?

Comment: Untrue, try $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_8=1$, $a_9=-2$.

Comment: $n=2$, $a_1=0$, $a_2=-1$ yields $-1\ le -2$

Comment: @Did  Good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If the $a_i$ are non-negative, then $a_i, a_i^2$ are similarly ordered and [Chebyshev’s Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) would allow you to conclude this.

If you allow all reals, then counter examples are already given above.